How can I format this text using the | character?
Having a text with several separators | I would like to format it by applying the following:

Take the first group, and put R. in front of it in red.

Take the second group and put the character * in red in front of it, removing | and leaving the text on the same line as (1)

Take the third group and put it in a new paragraph, preceded by V. in red.

Put the second group in a new paragraph preceded by R. in red and capitalizing the first letter, keeping in mind that sometimes the first or second character will not be a letter and should be ignored (for example, if it contains question marks, exclamation marks, quotation marks, etc.).


Below are some examples of text and the expected result:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,|consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.|Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.




Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,|“consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua”.|Ut enim
ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.



Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,|“¿consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua?”.|Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

How could I achieve this?

In none of your examples there are enough | for 4 items. Can we expect the input to always have 4 items? Why not simply use a single macro with 4 arguments but that strange syntax splitting on |?

The following implements your syntax. I don't see the advantage of this split approach though:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\splitbar{>{\SplitArgument{3}{|}}m}
  { \acedano_splitbar_output:nnnn #1 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \acedano_splitbar_output:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \textcolor { red } { R/. } ~ #1 ~
    \textcolor { red } { * }   ~ #2 \par
    \textcolor { red } { V/. } ~ #3 \par
    \textcolor { red } { R/. } ~ \text_titlecase_first:n {#4}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\fourargs{mmmm}
  { \acedano_splitbar_output:nnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\splitbar{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,|“¿consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua?”.|Ut enim ad minim
  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
  commodo consequat.|“¿consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua?”.}

\bigskip

\fourargs
  {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,}
  {%
    “¿consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
    dolore magna aliqua?”.%
  }
  {%
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.%
  }
  {%
    “¿consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
    dolore magna aliqua?”.%
  }
\end{document}



Is not working for me: Undefined control sequence splitbar. Please note that I am defining the command in a separate file where I have defined several commands and environments. As for the format with those separators, it is because that is how the data comes from a database. But as you rightly point out, I could change it to something more programmatically readable, like fourargs

@A.Cedano seems like you're either not inputting the file with this definition or trying to use this before you input that file.

The inclusion of the main-template file is done in the right place. I think the error is due to the fact that you use another type of syntax in your code (?). In my file I have several commands defined like this for example: \newcommand{\rbook}[1]{{ % ... some commands } }  but you use a different syntax starting with \NewDocumentCommand. Maybe that's the problem.

@A.Cedano no, that shouldn't be a problem (as long as you don't have a severely outdated LaTeX). To be sure you could put \usepackage{xparse} in your preamble and check again. If you want further assistance, please post the relevant part of your .log verbatimly (so not something you pretty printed). Otherwise, try to create a minimal example that reproduces your issue with as few lines of code as possible and ask a follow up question.
